# How to include a level of error in matching/comparing data frames in R

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, compare, match

I am new to R and am trying my best (and so far; so good) but I have hit a problem. I have two data frames, one with the theoretical values and the other with the experimental values, and the data frames are not the same length. I would like to compare the two data frames to find matching values between them. As is it theoretical vs experimental values, I need to include a level of error in matching the values, say ±0.5 from the theoretical value. This is where I having my problem- I don’t know how to include this error.

The data frames are quiet large but below is an example of what I have tried.

```
Theory <- c("195.0882",
            "196.0852",
            "196.0916",
            "300.1600",
            "288.1752",
            "289.1786",
            "290.1819",
            "393.2077",
            "394.2111")

Experi <- c("195.0312",
            "196.0340",
            "196.1251",
            "288.1856",
            "289.1786",
            "290.1819")


T <- data.frame(Theory)
E <- data.frame(Experi)
M1 <- merge.default(T, E)
M2 <- match(Theory, Experi)
M2
# [1] NA NA NA NA NA  5  6 NA NA
```

Both merge and match leave no room for error, and the compare package seems to be no help either.

Comment: There is a package on github called  `fuzzyjoin` - you can find it there - https://github.com/dgrtwo/fuzzyjoin

Comment: Do you want to try matching *every value* in `Theory` against *every value* in `Experi`? Or do the values line up in order, and so only parallel pairs of values need to be compared? Or are you looking to find at most one match for each value in `Theory`? What if there are two candidates for a match, but one is closer than the other?

Comment: I am looking to find a value from 'Experi' in 'Theory', with a level of error. So there is no need to match every value. Also the values are not in order, so no the parallel pairs comparison. If there are two candidates for a match, I'm hoping a can reduce the error level to get only one match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `data.table::foverlaps` function for merging with overlap. First we need to prepare the data, create ranges for Theory values.

```
library(data.table)

# set tolerance for merge
tolerance <- 0.5

# Theory data, prepare data with tolerance for Start/End
dt_T <- data.table(
  Theory = as.numeric(Theory),
  Start = as.numeric(Theory) - tolerance,
  End = as.numeric(Theory) + tolerance, 
  key= c("Start", "End"))

# Experi data, Start/End are the same
dt_E <- data.table(
  Experi = as.numeric(Experi),
  Start = as.numeric(Experi),
  End = as.numeric(Experi), 
  key= c("Start", "End"))

# merge with overlap
foverlaps(dt_E, dt_T)
#      Theory    Start      End   Experi  i.Start    i.End
# 1: 195.0882 194.5882 195.5882 195.0312 195.0312 195.0312
# 2: 196.0852 195.5852 196.5852 196.0340 196.0340 196.0340
# 3: 196.0916 195.5916 196.5916 196.0340 196.0340 196.0340
# 4: 196.0852 195.5852 196.5852 196.1251 196.1251 196.1251
# 5: 196.0916 195.5916 196.5916 196.1251 196.1251 196.1251
# 6: 288.1752 287.6752 288.6752 288.1856 288.1856 288.1856
# 7: 289.1786 288.6786 289.6786 289.1786 289.1786 289.1786
# 8: 290.1819 289.6819 290.6819 290.1819 290.1819 290.1819
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, you say you only want to get a single theoretical value for each experimental value, even if multiple theoretical values satisfy the tolerance. You imply that, if there are multiple candidates that satisfy the tolerance, you want to select the closest match of all candidates. But you also say that there is no need to match against every value. I think this is a contradiction. If you need to select the closest matching theoretical value of all theoretical values, then that means you need to compare each experimental value against *all* theoretical values to ensure that you select the closest match of all theoretical values.

The [`findInterval()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/findInterval.html) function is suitable for this purpose. By first sorting the theoretical vector, we can use it as the `vec` argument of `findInterval()`, which will allow a binary search to be used to find the lower bound on each experimental value. We can specify `all.inside=T` to ensure the returned indexes are all inside the sorted theoretical vector (and not pointing to the last element), and then perform an additional tiebreaker on the adjacent elements to add 1 when the upper element is actually closer to the experimental value than the lower element.

Finally, we can apply the tolerance. It appears from your question that you may want to return NA for experimental values that have no matching theoretical value, IOW where there is no theoretical value that satisfies the tolerance. We can achieve this requirement easily at this point by overwriting the theoretical values that were discovered in the previous step with NA if they do not satisfy the tolerance against their corresponding experimental value.

Also, minor point: I'm not sure why you defined the vectors as characters. We need numeric values to perform these operations.

Hence:

```
theory <- c(195.0882,196.0852,196.0916,300.16,288.1752,289.1786,290.1819,393.2077,394.2111);
experi <- c(195.0312,196.034,196.1251,288.1856,289.1786,290.1819);

## sort theory for findInterval() binary search
theory <- sort(theory);

## get closest match for each experi element
i <- findInterval(experi,theory,all.inside=T);
inc <- which(abs(theory[i+1L]-experi)<abs(theory[i]-experi));
i[inc] <- i[inc]+1L;

## init result vector
res <- theory[i];

## replace with NA any result elements whose deviations exceed the tolerance
res[abs(res-experi)>0.5] <- NA_real_;

## show result in a nice format
data.frame(experi,res,error=experi-res);
##     experi      res   error
## 1 195.0312 195.0882 -0.0570
## 2 196.0340 196.0852 -0.0512
## 3 196.1251 196.0916  0.0335
## 4 288.1856 288.1752  0.0104
## 5 289.1786 289.1786  0.0000
## 6 290.1819 290.1819  0.0000
```